# Comparing rates of growth with Big O

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

This is a homework problem regarding comparing rates of growth for a Big O function.

a) $\log(n^2) = O(\log(n))$
b) $\log(n^2) = O(n)$
c) $\log(n^2) = O(n^2)$
d) All of the above

My inclination is to say that that A is incorrect and that B and C are correct, which wouldn't make sense. I don't really know how to go about solving this.

Comment: $\log(n^2) = 2\log n$

Answer (score 0):

Recall
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)= \mathcal{O}(g(n))
\end{align}
if there exists $C>0$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(n)| \leq C g(n)
\end{align}
for all $n$.

a) Observe
\begin{align}
|\log(n^2)| = |2\log n| \leq 2 \log n
\end{align}
(Of course everything is equal, but I wanted to make a point).

b) Observe
\begin{align}
|\log(n^2)| = |2\log n| \leq 2 n.
\end{align}

c) Observe
\begin{align}
|\log(n^2)|= |2\log n| \leq 2n^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you can find positive integers $M$ and $n_{0}$ such that $f(n) \le M g(n)$ for all $n \ge n_{0}$ then $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$.

Answer is all of the above. You should be able to work out the answers directly using the definition above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is A.

Log(n<sup>2</sup>) = 2*log(n) and log(n) is the only growth rate in that because it's a constant multiplied by the growth.

Constants don't impact growth.